# How can I process at most a certain number of elements from a list?

Tags: python, loops

Using looping as follows to list n files from a directory:

```
myfiles = glob.glob("*.xml")
files = len(myfiles)

count = 0
myfiles.sort()
files_to_process = 3
for filename in myfiles:
   count += 1
   print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), count ,'of', files, '|', filename)
   if count == files_to_process:
      break
```

is there an alternative way to iterate only through n times other than using break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myfiles = glob.glob("*.xml")
files = len(myfiles)

count = 0
myfiles.sort()
files_to_process = 3
for filename in myfiles[:files_to_process]:
   count += 1
   print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), count ,'of', files, '|', filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myfiles = glob.glob("*.xml")
files = len(myfiles)

myfiles.sort()
files_to_process = 3

for i in range(min(files_to_process, files)):
  print (time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), i+1 ,'of', files, '|', myfiles[i])
```

Comment: This is a nice clean solution, but it will give an `IndexError` when there are fewer than three files in the list.

Comment: Added in a min() to avoid that IndexError - not quite as clean anymore though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take only the first `count` file names with `myfiles[:count]` or `itertools.islice(myfiles, count)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `zip`: the behaviour is to stop after exhausting whichever sequence is shorter. Zipping with a range also saves you having to manually update a counter.

```py
myfiles = glob.glob("*.xml")
files = len(myfiles)

myfiles.sort()
files_to_process = 3

for filename, count in zip(myfiles, range(1, files_to_process+1)):
    print(time.strftime("%I:%M:%S"), count, 'of', files, '|', filename)
```

That said, this solution is not idiomatic, and I don't think the code is better than the version using `break`.